# wrong values with Shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Hi I am new to programming.

While trying to execute the script below, 
with an input file of this form (in this case they are called `nohd*.txt` files)

```
NSGEAPKNFGLDVKITGESENDRDLGTAPGGTLNDIG
IIIIMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIII
```

I want to count the columns that have text from file `d.txt`, see next.

```
D
O
```

to do this I wrote the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
for z in {1..141}
do
        a=0
        l=$(tail -1 nohd$z.txt | wc -m)
        x=$(cat d.txt)
                for ((p; p<=l; p++))
                do
                        if [ "$(cut -c $p nohd$z.txt)" = "$x" ] ; then
                                a=$((a+1))
                                p=$((p+1))
                        fi
                done
        echo $a
done
```

I'm running this script using `./script`
it shows this error:

```
cut: invalid byte/character position ‘{1..351}’
```

it turns correctly only the first value, for the rest of values it turns 0 the expected output is in the following form

```
5
20
4
```

Please, can anyone help me with this?
Thank u

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Could you please [edit] your question and show us what output you expect here? Your script is taking a very complicated approach and has some mistakes so it is hard to understand what you are trying to do with it.

Comment: Also, are you _sure_ you are running this in bash and not `sh`? How are you executing the script?

Comment: I'm trying to count to content of the file d.txt in a series of files.

Comment: I'm running this script in terminal

Comment: Yes, how? `sh script.sh`? `./script.sh`? `bash script.sh`? Something else? Please [edit] your question and clarify. Also, please show your expected output as I requested before.

Comment: ./script
only the first value is correct (5), for the rest of values it turns 0
the expected output isin the following form
```
5
20
4
```

Comment: (1) If your files were transposed, they would be _vastly_ easier to work with for your task. A simple `grep` would suffice. (2) Maybe it's time to take somethig like Python, or Ruby, or Julia, or whatever higher-than-shell level language you have around. Complex string processing is not a shell's strong point.

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question to add your expected output and show us how you run your script. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning.

Comment: how can I do this job with `grep`? I've tried it and it was unsuccessful

Comment: Why would you have 3 lines of output if you only look for 2 letters? Please show us the output you expect *from the example input you gave*. We need this to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: no I'm looking for the entire column that contains in the first line letter D and in the second line the letter O, this operation will be done for 143 files, named as follow nohd1.txt ... nohd142.txt, so this script should turn out 143 values (for an example of an output I've given just 3 values)

Comment: The value of `p` should be `1` for the first comparison with `cut`, so try to change your loop to `for ((p=1; p<l; p++))` and you probably don't need to increment `p` with `p=$((p+1))` (remove it).

Comment: finally, it works. I'm so grateful to u. Thank u too much

Comment: You **really** don't want to do this in bash (or any version of sh).   Use awk or perl or anything but sh.  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/7696)

Answer (score 1):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Slurp;

# read d.txt and turn into a regular expression.
my $re = '^(' . join ('|',read_file('./d.txt', chomp => 1)) . ')$';

# read input files and print location of matches.
while (<>) {
  for (my $i=0;$i <= length; $i++) {
    printf "%s\n", $i+1 if (substr($_,$i,1) =~ m/$re/o);
  }
}
```

This perl script prints the positions of every `D' and 'O' character in the input lines.

Save as, e.g. `islem.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x islem.pl`, and run it like this:

```
$ ./islem.pl nohd*.txt
12
22
24
35
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
```

The above output is from saving your sample data as `nohd1.txt`.

---

I think I misread your question.  It looks like you want the **count** of matches on a line, not the **position** of every match.  If that's what you wanted, try this instead:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use File::Slurp;

# read d.txt and turn into a regular expression.
my $re = '^(' . join ('|',read_file('./d.txt', chomp => 1)) . ')$';

# read input files and print location of matches.
while (<>) {
  my $count=0;
  for (my $i=0;$i <= length; $i++) {
    $count++ if (substr($_,$i,1) =~ m/$re/o);
  };
  print $count;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./islem2.pl nohd*
4
13
```

This is easily adapted to many variations.  For example, if if you wanted to print the filename and line number along with the corresponding count in `:` delimited format:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use File::Slurp;

# read d.txt and turn into a regular expression.
my $re = '^(' . join ('|',read_file('./d.txt', chomp => 1)) . ')$';

# read input files and print location of matches.
while (<>) {
  my $count=0;
  for (my $i=0;$i <= length; $i++) {
    $count++ if (substr($_,$i,1) =~ m/$re/o);
  };
  print "$ARGV:$.:$count";
} continue {
  # explicitly close the current file on eof to reset the line counter
  # after each input file because perl only has a cumulative line
  # counter ($.) rather than both FR and FNR like awk.
  close ARGV if eof;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./islem3.pl nohd*.txt
nohd1.txt:1:4
nohd1.txt:2:13
```